# Align function definition ranges in subequation environment

Tags: align

I would like to align the function definition ranges in the `subequation` environment. Does anyone know a simple way to do that? At the moment, I simply have them separated by `\quad`.

```
\begin{subequations}
    \begin{empheq}{align}
        S_e &= a_{gd} \,  S \left[ 1 + \frac{(2.5 \eta - 1) T}{T_B} \right] \quad (0 \leq T \geq T_B) \\
        S_e &= 2.5 \, a_{gd} \,  S \, \eta \quad (T_B \leq T \geq T_C) \\
        S_e &= 2.5 \, a_{gd} \,  S \, \eta  \frac{T_C}{T} \quad (T_ \leq T \geq T_D) \\
        S_e &= 2.5 \, a_{gd} \,  S \, \eta  \frac{T_C \, T_D}{T^2} \quad (T_D \geq T)
         \label{eq:response_spectra}
    \end{empheq}
\end{subequations}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a further column in `align` or, if the spacing is too large for your taste, use `alignat` instead.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}

\noindent
Either
\begin{subequations}
    \begin{empheq}{align}
        S_e &= a_{gd} \,  S \left[ 1 + \frac{(2.5 \eta - 1) T}{T_B} \right] && (0 \leq T \geq T_B) \\
        S_e &= 2.5 \, a_{gd} \,  S \, \eta                                  && (T_B \leq T \geq T_C) \\
        S_e &= 2.5 \, a_{gd} \,  S \, \eta  \frac{T_C}{T}                   && (T_C \leq T \geq T_D) \\
        S_e &= 2.5 \, a_{gd} \,  S \, \eta  \frac{T_C \, T_D}{T^2}          && (T_D \geq T)
    \end{empheq}
\end{subequations}
or
\begin{subequations}
    \begin{empheq}{alignat=2}
        S_e &= a_{gd} \,  S \left[ 1 + \frac{(2.5 \eta - 1) T}{T_B} \right] &\qquad& (0 \leq T \geq T_B) \\
        S_e &= 2.5 \, a_{gd} \,  S \, \eta                                  && (T_B \leq T \geq T_C) \\
        S_e &= 2.5 \, a_{gd} \,  S \, \eta  \frac{T_C}{T}                   && (T_C \leq T \geq T_D) \\
        S_e &= 2.5 \, a_{gd} \,  S \, \eta  \frac{T_C \, T_D}{T^2}          && (T_D \geq T)
    \end{empheq}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that you had two `T_` which caused the following relation to be rendered as subscript. I replaced it by `T_C` but I don't know what is/was intended. (Things like T<sub>B</sub> < T > T<sub>C</sub> look very suspicious to me.)

Note also that 1) right now `empheq` isn't exactly doing anything, and 2) in the way you are using `\label`, you are giving the label only to the last equation.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, indeed, I wrote `\geq` instead of `\leq`, so it looks like ( Tb < T > Tc )

Comment: Will it work if I label each equation separately then?

Comment: @euler132 If you want to label the whole "block" then you should put `\label` outside of `empheq`, e.g. immediately after `\begin{subequations}`. Of course you can add a further label to each single equation.